# Validar una cadena de caracteres en Regex en JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de validar la siguiente cadena de caracteres **'dddd-dddd-dddd-dddd'** con JS, donde **'d'** es un cualquier digito.

La condición que debo validar, es que la cadena puede o no contener el ultimo fragmento de dígitos, a continuación pongo algunos ejemplos validos y no validos.

**Cadenas validas**:

- *0201-4565-1*
- *0201-4565-12*
- *0201-4565-123*
- *0201-4565-1234*
- *0201-4565-1234-4*
- *0201-4565-1234-4569*

**Cadenas no validas**:

- *0201-*
- *0201-4565-*
- *0201-4565-1238-*

Esta es la expresión regular con la que estoy validando la cadena:

```
const regex = /\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{1,4}((-)?\d{1,})?/;
```

Pero cuando ingreso la cadena ***'0201-4565-1238-'*** y la valido con la expresión regresa `true` como cadena valida, siendo que esta no es valida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión es casi correcta, solo faltan unas modificaciones:

La agrupación final `((-)?\d{1,})?` estás especificando que el guión es opcional, lo que permitiría agregar solo números, entre 1 y... ¿muchos? Haciendo que expresiones como las siguientes sean válidas:

```
0201-4565-12345678
0201-4565-1234-123456789
```

Ese último grupo debe ser `(-\d{1,4})?` para hacerlo opcional y, en caso de que se incluya, debe tener el guión antes de los números, entre 1 y 4.

Finalmente, solo necesitas especificar que se tome en cuenta toda la cadena con un circunflejo `^` (inicio) y un signo de moneda `$` (fin) para especificar dónde comienza y termina la búsqueda de coincidencias.

```js
const rx = /^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{1,4}(-\d{1,4})?$/;

console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-1238-')); // false solo guión
console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-1238')); // true
console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-1238-5')); // true
console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-1238-567890')); // false, muchos números al final
```

Probablemente, todavía sea necesario modificar, para garantizar que el tercer grupo tiene 4 dígitos en caso de haber un cuarto grupo.

**Edición:** Garantizar que el tercer grupo tenga 4 dígitos si es que hay un cuarto grupo, desglosado:

```
\d{4}-\d{4}-    // Dos grupos de 4 dígitos, seguidos de guión obligatorios
(               // Abrir paréntesis para incluir condicional
    (\d{1,4})   // Si no hay cuarto grupo, permitir 1 a 4 dígitos
    |           // Condicional OR
    (           // Agrupar últimos dos fragmentos
        \d{4}   // Tercer grupo debe tener 4 dígitos
        -       // El guión es obligatorio
        \d{1,4} // El cuarto grupo debe tener entre 1 y 4 dígitos
    )           // Fin de últimos dos fragmentos
)               // Fin de condicional
```

```js
const rx = /^\d{4}-\d{4}-((\d{1,4})|(\d{4}-\d{1,4}))$/;

console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-128'));      // verdadero, no hay cuarto grupo
console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-128-5'));    // falso, tercer grupo debe tener 4 dígitos
console.log(rx.test('0201-4565-1238-567')); // verdadero, tercer grupo con 4 dígitos
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me puedes ayudar con la expresión para validar si el tercer grupo tiene 4 dígitos, esto es lo que llevo, pero no me queda. `/^(\d{4}-\d{4})(-?:(?=\d{4})(\d{4}-\d{1,4})?|(?:(?=\d{1,3})\d{1,3}|(-\d{1,4})?))$/`

Comment: @TimeToCode, revisa el último fragmento de código agregado a la respuesta.

Comment: no sabia que se podían declarar de manera mas simple las condiciones booleanas, de verdad aprecio mucho tu ayuda.